# Trying to export function using export {} causing errors

Tags: javascript, webpack, path

I'm learning to code on my own so to practice webscraping I thought I'd make a program which displays a famous persons birth on a user inputted date on one side using cheerio, while on the other it uses an API to get the temp of a user inputted city. Here is the github: https://github.com/Yummy275/Date_Weather_Celebbirths

Im having trouble with famous_getter.js in ./src . When I try to add `export { getName }` to be able to use the function in other files similar to all my other files, I get an error when I try to webpack or run node famous_getter.js after I add `import {getName} from "./famous_getter"` to index.js to test the function. Any help is appreciated. Thanks for looking.

EDIT - adding errors

Webpack error(its this repeated a bunch for different things "cant resolve 'x" in":

> ERROR in ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js Module not found: Error:
> Can't resolve 'fs' in
> '/home/yummy/Projects/DateWeatherCelebbday/node_modules/request/lib'
> @ ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js 3:9-22  @
> ./node_modules/request/request.js  @ ./node_modules/request/index.js
> @ ./src/famous_getter.js  @ ./src/index.js

node famous_getter.js error:

```
node famous_getter
(node:257160) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/home/yummy/Projects/DateWeatherCelebbday/src/famous_getter.js:25
export { getName };
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

In my GitHub famous_getter.js works when I run node famous_getter.js . When I get rid of my test (getName(famousbirthsURL)) and try to add export {getName}, thats when errors happen.

Comment: you didn't do `npm install` after updating your package.json

Comment: @arslan2012 the errors are regarding `fs`, which is part of nodejs, and not a separate npm module.

Comment: @Olian04 I cloned his project and ran it fine, so I assumed it's an node_module error

Comment: @arslan2012 I tried doing npm install in /DateWeatherCelebday, but im still getting errors

Answer (score 2):

**Attempt #2:**

***Edit:** I have taken all edits to the OP's question and info in comments in this response.*

Looks like you are targeting node and not web.
The default target for webpack is web.
You need to add a target: 'node' in your webpack file.

```
    const path = require("path");

    module.exports = {
        target: 'node',
        entry: "./src/index.js",
        output: {
            filename: "main.js",
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        },
    };
```

After adding this, webpack ran successfully and built the assets.
[image]

Launched http-server ./ on the dist folder and browsed home page.
Screenshot:

[image]
**Attempt #1:**

I downloaded the project from Github and ran webpack.

The assets are building successfully.

I also added the export { getName } to famous_getter.js and ran webpack.

Build is successful. I am not encountering the errors.

Perhaps, something is wrong with your environment or node_modules cache.
Try a fresh install and webpack.

Screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok. Your code on GH is not having the famous_getter import in index.js. I am adding it there for importing getName and trying.

Comment: Able to repro now.

Comment: OO I apologize. I edited my post to make that more clear! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your edit to webpack.config and it does webpack successfuly now. Im wondering why my other stuff I had on the page is gone now though? When I launch server I get this error in the console: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:1)
    at a (main.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:157)
    at a (main.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:1)
    at a (main.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:1)
    at a (main.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:127)
    at a (main.js:1)

Answer (score 1):

Lets read the error thoroughly: `Error: Can't resolve './src/index.js' in '/home/yummy/Projects/DateWeatherCelebbday/src'`.

- What does it say? Its looking for a file `index.js` that's located at the relative position `./src/index.js`. The `.` at the begining means that we are trying to resolve the path in a relative manner.
- Relative to what? In this case its relative to the path
  `/home/yummy/Projects/DateWeatherCelebbday/src`. In other words the
  program is looking for a file at
  `/home/yummy/Projects/DateWeatherCelebbday/src/src/index.js`, which
  likely contain one too many `src`.
- Try changing either the relative path to `./index.js`, or navigate to `/home/yummy/Projects/DateWeatherCelebbday` and run the original command.

Comment: I noticed that! I'm sorry, I updated my post to reflect me trying in the correct directory. Thank you.